# Create new matrix from existing matrices java

Tags: java, matrix

I have a matrix A, B, C, D of dimension n*m which I already created. I want to create a new matrix from that existing matrices.

Can anyone tell me how to create that type of matrix using Java programming?

Comment: Please show us some code so that we may help you.

Comment: You need to be more descriptive than that.

Comment: @user3454526 What is your intention..Please add more details.

Comment: for example, a new matrix T will be created from existing matrices A, B, C, D which denoted: 
T = 
[A B 
C D] of 2 dimensional array

Comment: or can say it is a block matrix where A, B, C, and D are themselves matrices, is a block matrix, for example: 

A = [0 2; 2 0] 
B = [3 3 3; 3 3 3] 
C = [4 4; 4 4; 4 4] 
D = [5 0 5; 0 5 0; 5 0 5]; 
therefore, it is the matrix

 [0 2 3 3 3; 2 0 3 3 3; 4 4 5 0 5; 4 4 0 5 0; 4 4 5 0 5].

Comment: it seem to be clear details in this website: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BlockMatrix.html